# Lumen reading certain database table?

Tags: mysql, laravel, lumen

So I followed this tutorial and made a working API.
https://auth0.com/blog/developing-restful-apis-with-lumen/

But when I tried adding new tables, I can't seem to read the new table with the API, I have no idea where to 'link' the database (something like databasename.tablename) as the tutorial uses json to read the author table without specifying database name or table name.

From AuthorController.php

```
public function showAllAuthors()
    {
        return response()->json(Author::all());
    }
```

It reads properly, however, when I created new migrations which added a new table 'books', then added a new controller, say BookController.php

```
public function showAllAuthors()
    {
        return response()->json(Book::all()); //?? I have tried Book, Books, and even Author
    }
```

And also added a new router:

```
  $router->get('contest',  ['uses' => 'BookController@showAllBooks']);
```

How should I read the database 'databasename' and table 'books'?
I have Googled the problem but I can't find anything useful.

EDIT: I forgot adding `use App\Book;` which solves the problem, thanks to Pavel in the comment.

Comment: Have you created the migration for book table?

Comment: yes, I just don't know how the controller can get the correct database and table

Comment: So what's the problem? Which error do you have?

Comment: So the database is like 'databasename.authors', which is called from the controller 'return response()->json(Author::all());'
If I want to call 'databasename.books', how can I read it from the controller?

Comment: I tried 'return response()->json(Book::all());' but it doesn't work

Comment: Create model `Book` for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169724/discussion-between-rizki-hadiaturrasyid-and-pavel).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using

`public function showAllBooks{
    return response()->json(DB::table('books')->get()));
}`